# Android: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'gpg'', error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gnupg

**Sharing it in Q&A Style**

**Problem Statement**

I cloned a new project and it had `gpg` encryption. I installed `gpg` via running `brew install gnupg` in the terminal. I confirmed the installation via running `which gpg` command in the terminal and it gave me `/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg` path. I tried to build the project but it was giving the error as below:

**Error**

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
Build file '/Users/srdpatel/androidProjects/projectName/oneOfTheDirectoiesOutOfThreeSiblings/app/build.gradle' line: 10
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'gpg''
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'gpg''
> org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'gpg'
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gpg" (in directory "/Users/srdpatel/androidProjects/projectName/oneOfTheDirectoriesOutOfThreeSiblings"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

**App Level Gradle Line 10**

```
apply from: '../credentials/crypto.gradle'
```

**Other information**

1. gpg is already installed via `brew install gnupg` and it is updated one only.
2. The command `which gpg` in the terminal shows `/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the script `apply from: '../credentials/crypto.gradle'`. We can press `shift` two times in Android Studio and type `crypto.gradle` to go to that file. There, we can find the word `gpg`. The result should look like below:

```
def result = execute("gpg", ...
```

Here, we need to replace the `"gpg"` with our absolute gpg path that we get from `which gpg` command in the terminal. For me, it gave me: `/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg`. So, we need to edit the existing `"gpg"` script as below:

```
def result = execute("/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg", ...
```

Now, we can click on `Try again` to build our Android project and this time, it should not throw the  `A problem occurred starting process 'command 'gpg'', ... error=2, No such file or directory`.